# Oracle connection in SSAS cube very slow

Tags: oracle, connection, ssas

I am trying to connect to oracle 11g in SSAS 2016. The connection is extremely slow and the dimension processing never finishes. (there are only 200 rows in dimension sql). I am using OraOLEDB. How can i fix this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

on the Oracle DB side you can examine gv$session to see the status ... of your session, if it is in a wait state or on CPU.  In my experience, DB side tuning begins with identifying the session and SQL it is running, then tune manually or with SQL Tuning Advisor (if licensed).  Sometimes the problem is at the DB instance level, and the ADDM advisor will help (if licensed).